# Does GetTickCount() include time spent suspended or hibernated?

Tags: winapi

To clarify, I mean time spent while the *system* is suspended/hibernated, not the calling thread (GetTickCount() returns the number of milliseconds since system boot).

Comment: Silly question, what happens when you try this? I would because I'm curious about the answer too, but I don't have a suspendable Windows machine handy at the moment.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

As far as I know, GetTickCount is unrelated to threads and counts the time since the system has started. But it is better to use [GetTickCount64](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms724411(VS.85).aspx) to avoid the 49.7 day roleover.

By the way, to get what you want you need the [GetThreadTimes](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms683237(VS.85).aspx) function. It records the creation and exit time and the amount of time the thread has spend in user or kernel space. So you have a nice way to calculate the amount of time spend.

Ok, I missed the "system" part of the question. But that is simple. When in hibernation GetTickCount continues the counting. Because people have suffered from the 49.7 days bug when the computer was in hibernate most of the time. See [link text](http://dot-y.blogspot.com/2008/07/windows-programming-funny-gettickcount.html) here for more information.

Comment: I think the original question refers to whether the *system* is suspended or hibernated, not a particular thread.

Comment: Point. Completely missed that one.

Answer (score 6):

Short answer : Yes.

Longer answer: Read the [GetTickCount()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms724408(VS.85).aspx) docs: It's the ***elapsed*** time since system startup, and even MS wouldn't suggest that time stands still while your computer is hibernating...

Answer (score 3):

For any one looking for answer under Windows CE platform, from docs:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms885645.aspx

you can read:

> For Release configurations, this function returns the number of
>   milliseconds since the device booted, ***excluding any time that the
>   system was suspended***. GetTickCount starts at 0 on boot and then counts
>   up from there.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, GetTickCount does include suspend/hibernate time.

In the following python script I call the Sleep API to wait 40 seconds to give me a chance to put the computer into hibernate mode, and I print the time before and after, and the tick count difference after.

```
import win32api
import time
print time.strftime("%H:%M:%S", time.localtime())
before = win32api.GetTickCount()
print "sleep"
win32api.Sleep(40000)
print time.strftime("%H:%M:%S", time.localtime())
print str(win32api.GetTickCount()-before)
```

Output:

```
17:44:08
sleep
17:51:30
442297
```

If GetTickCount did not include the time during hibernate it would be much less than the time I hibernated for, but it matches the actual time elapsed (7 minutes 22 seconds equals 442 seconds, i.e. 442000 millisecond "ticks").

Answer (score 0):

`GetTickCount()` gives you the time in milliseconds since the computer booted. it has nothing to do with the process calling it.

Comment: I suppose the best way to find out is to just test it.

Answer (score -3):

No, `GetTickCount()` does not include the time the system spend during hibernate.
A simple test proves this.

in Python:

```
import win32api
win32api.GetTickCount()
```

-- do hibernate --

```
win32api.GetTickCount()
```

and you'll see the result...

Comment: flat wrong and not helpful -- this bit of python has no way of allowing you to hibernate between the GetTickCount calls