# Environment.TickCount while breaking from code

Tags: .net

Does `Environment.TickCount` pause when you hit a break point in visual studio? I was wondering as I am trying to get to the bottom of some performance issues in my code however I break at certain points to look at some values and was wondering if these breaks allow the ticks to continue or not as these will of course add to the totals if this is the case.

Comment: I guess Environment.TickCount()  cannot be paused at all. (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.environment.tickcount.aspx)

Comment: Time keeps on slipping, slipping, slipping, into the Fuuuture.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No it does not. The value returned is the "A 32-bit signed integer containing the amount of time in milliseconds that has passed since the last time the computer was started." ([MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.environment.tickcount.aspx)), that is a global counter inside Windows / the computer that does not stop when one application is suspended. It [looks](https://stackoverflow.com/a/513116/21567) it is not even affected by the computer itself being suspend (hibernated) or a kernel debugger pausing the OS itself.

Actually, it might even be smaller than it was before you stopped on the breakpoint, given that it wraps around after ~24.9 days ;-)

Comment: Thanks I wasnt sure if it meant the development environment when it says Environment.TickCount.

Answer (score 1):

No it doesn't stop. It maps to the WinApi call `GetTickCount` which counts the milliseconds since the last reboot. It's a value that's the same across all processes. I'm not sure how it interacts with hibernation, but debugging certainly doesn't stop it.