# Is it safe to use GetTickCount to increment time?

Tags: delphi

I have a thread that is created in system startup. It's job is to sign PDF files in demand. To sign, I need to get the server date/time. To avoid going to server every time, in the creation of the thread I get the server time and the current tick count (`GetTickCount`), and when I need the current date I calculate using this values:

```
CurrentDate := (FServerDate+ (GetTickCount - FInitialTick) / MSecsPerDay);
```

Is that a safe thing to do? The code works, but is there some downside using this aprouch?

Comment: One obvious downside is explained in the documentation of GetTickCount. Another downside could be, your signature won't be in synch with the server after some time, or if the server's time adjusts. That would depend on your requirements. To avoid downsides to some extent you could synch at fixed intervals I guess.

Comment: Well, gettickcount64 would definitely be a better choice...  But even then, my first worry would be "What happens to the tick count when the PC enter sleep mode?". A much better way would be simply to calculate the offset between `Now` and your server's time. But then again, daylight saving issue can crop in, amongs other things.

Comment: According to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/513116/6137384), it keeps counting when sleeping

Comment: Yes, I choose not to use `Now` because the date/time of users computer could be wrong

Comment: @SertacAkyuz when you say the downside in the documentation, is that about the 49 days?

Comment: Yep. That's also the reason Ken suggests the version that returns a 64 bit value.

Comment: Thanks, I'll replace it. 
Delphi does not map this function, right? I'll have to declare like this:
`function GetTickCount64: int64; external kernel32 name 'GetTickCount64';`

Comment: Maybe it's just my personal paranoia, but I'd probably use both `Now` and `GetTickCount64`.  And if they end up "disagreeing" between eachother, then refresh from server.  Also, I don't think getting the server time alone is enough, you need the timezone too. I'd probably do it even if the server is in the same building, in case it's not configured properly (see.. paranoia! ... and it prevents the code from breaking if the server or the client ever move).  But... yeah.  Time management is hard. https://www.wired.com/2012/06/falsehoods-programmers-believe-about-time/

Comment: When I get the server time, the server gets the date/time from the database, so I think that this part is trustable

Comment: The only 99.99% reliable method is to always ask the server. Everything else will come short in terms of reliability. It all depends on how much reliability/precision you need.

Comment: You usually don't need timezone info, and thus don't have to worry about daylight savings, if you handle everything using UTC only. For instance, using `GetSystemTime()`+`SystemTimeToDateTime()` instead of using `Now()` (which uses `GetLocalTime()` instead). If the server doesn't give you UTC, well, then ...

Comment: Is it safe depends really on what the requirements are for the time. Does it need to be accurate? How accurate?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`GetTickCount` has a 32-bit resolution, so it is deprecated and `GetTickCount64` should be used instead, with a `FInitialTick: Int64` associated variable. You may see some round-up error if your OS session stands for more than 40 days.

Here is a version working with XP (if you need to maintain it):

```
var
  GetTickXP: Int64Rec;

function GetTickCount64ForXP: Int64; stdcall;
var t32: cardinal;
    t64: Int64Rec absolute result;
begin // warning: GetSystemTimeAsFileTime() is fast, but not monotonic!
  t32 := Windows.GetTickCount;
  t64 := GetTickXP; // (almost) atomic read
  if t32<t64.Lo then
    inc(t64.Hi); // wrap-up overflow after 49 days
  t64.Lo := t32;
  GetTickXP := t64; // (almost) atomic write
end; // warning: FPC's GetTickCount64 doesn't handle 49 days wrap :(
```

In your use case, it is safe to use such a formula, and avoid asking the server to return a timestamp each time. If the client is not meant to be restarted after a while, you may ask the server timestamp every hour or day, just to be sure that both sides are on synch.

We use [a similar trick in our mORMot ORM](http://blog.synopse.info/post/2012/08/01/Managing-unique-properties) with success since years. It is just build-in in the RestFul ORM, with fields automatically filled with the creation or modification time (`TCreateTime` and `TModTime` fields).

Last tip: ensure you use UTC date/time everywhere in your system. :)